# Prove non computability of a function defined on partial and total functions

Tags: functions, computability

I have to prove that the following function is not computable

$$ f(x) = if\ (x\ is \ even\ and\ f_{x/2}\ is \ total\ ) \ then\ 1\ else \ (x\ is \ even\ and\ f_{x/2}\ is \ partial\ )\ then\ 0\ else\ \bot$$

I was trying to count on the fact that I have no possibility  to show that $f_{x/2}$ is total by means of a TM (I think). But I have no clue on how to prove this. I was also trying to reduce the function to a set on TM indexes and try to apply the Rice Theorem, but I couldn't do it. Is someone able to give me a clue on how to proceed?

EDIT: I thought that maybe the proof hides in the meaning of total and partial, even though I do not know how to formally prove this. My guess is that for a given index $x$, even if I could prove that $f_{x/2}$ is not defined for a least 1 value, I cannot be sure that for such value the TM cannot stop (i.e. accept the input) in the future, and therefore I cannot conclude it is partial. Moreover, in order to define the function as total I would need to try every possible input, and even after a long time where all the input I tried caused the machine to stop I cannot conclude that $f_{x/2}$ is total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: if your function was computable, then you would be able to decide the TOTAL problem (deciding whether or not a Turing machine halts on all inputs) - which is undecidable.

We first fix an encoding of Turing Machines.

We use the following reduction: suppose that you have a machine $M$ that computes $f$. Now, we design a machine $N$, which accepts $x$ if the machine $M_x$ is total.

$N$ work as follows: on input $x$, it runs $M$ on the input $2x$, and gets the result $y = f(2x)$. Now, if $y = 1$, $N$ accepts; otherwise, it rejects.

It is easy to prove that $N$ accepts $x$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $M_x$ is total. Hence, $f$ is undecidable.

One point that I overlooked in the previous proof is the fact that TOTAL is undecidable. This can be done easily, by considering a machine which does the same thing regardless of its input (and so it hats on *all* inputs iff it halts on *any* input). With this idea in mind, the reduction to the Halting Problem is then easy to define.

Comment: This is very clear and concise. Thank you for the clarification.